# How to instantiate a class that is nested inside a class from outside that .java file (Java)?

Tags: java, class, nested, instance, instantiation

I have two classes, Main and SPBHomeHelp. Here is the code for Main:

```
public class Main{

      SPBHomeHelp homeHelp;

      public Main(){

            homeHelp = new SPBHomeHelp();

            Home home = new Home();

      }

 }
```

Here is the code for SPBHomeHelp:

```
public class SPBHomeHelp{

      public SPBHomeHelp(){

      }

      public class Home{

            public Home(){

                  System.out.println("Entered Home Constructor");

            }

      }

}
```

Main and SPBHomeHelp are two different .java files. I can easily declare and instantiate an instance for SPBHomeHelp. But I want to have an instance of Home, which is a class nested inside SPBHomeHelp, in Main too. I tried:

```
Home home = new Home();
```

because Home is a public, but that doesn't work. How can I create an instance of Home in Main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`home` is an instance of the inner-class `Home` type (from the class `SPBHomeHelp`). You need an instance of that class (that is`homeHelp`), in order to construct a `Home` instance. I think you're looking for something like

```
SPBHomeHelp.Home home = homeHelp.new Home();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to implement this:

**First,**, just like the answer you accepted:

```
SPBHomeHelp.Home home = new SPBHomeHelp().new Home();
```

**Second**, make your `Home` `static`, then, in your `Main.main()` method,

`SPBHomeHelp.Home home = new SPBHomeHelp.Home();`

will be OK.

PS: what is the difference between `static inner class` and `non-static inner class` is: in a `non-static inner class`, there is a `this` which refer to the outer class, which means you can use fields and methods of the outer class in a `non-static inner class`. But you can't use fields and methods of the outer class in a `static inner class` except they are also `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class `Home` to `static`, and `static import` your `Home` class.

```
public class SPBHomeHelp{

      public SPBHomeHelp(){

      }

      public static class Home{

            public Home(){

                  System.out.println("Entered Home Constructor");

            }

      }

}
```

Main:

```
static import SPBHomeHelp.Home;
public class Main{

      SPBHomeHelp homeHelp;

      public Main(){

            homeHelp = new SPBHomeHelp();

            Home home = new Home();

      }

 }
```